# Join 2 structures with the same fieldnames by an 'ID' field in Matlab

Tags: matlab, join, struct, merge

Join 2 structures with the same field names by an 'ID' field in Matlab

I have 2 structures:

```
s2010.name = 'fred';
s2010.wage = 8;
s2010(2).name = 'alice';
s2010(2).wage = 9;
s2010(3).name = 'frank';
s2010(3).wage = 10;


s2011.name = 'alice';
s2011.wage = 10;
s2011(2).name = 'frank';
s2011(2).wage = 11;
s2011(3).name = 'peter';
s2011(3).wage = 12;
```

I would like to join these 2 structures by their common name in order to obtain the following:

```
s2years.name = 'alice';
s2years.wage2010 = 9;
s2years.wage2011 = 10;
s2years(2).name = 'frank';
s2years(2).wage2010 = 10;
s2years(2).wage2011 = 11;
```

Notice that fred and peter do not appear in the structure I would like to obtain only the common names. I would like to keep the wages for both years in separate fields in the result structure.

Is there any way to do this? Is it better to convert first these 2 sets to another object (e.g. dataset/table)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems this question is attracting. Here's my version -

```
[name,ind2010,ind2011] = intersect({s2010.name},{s2011.name});
s2years = struct('name', name, ...
    'wage2010', {s2010(ind2010).wage}, ...
    'wage2011', {s2011(ind2011).wage});
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about `intersect`.

Comment: It's also interesting to me that it can combine many lines of code into one. See latest edit.

Comment: I deleted my answer as being irrelevant after seeing even the previous edit.